# How to read GC420t printer's status?

Tags: c#, usb, polling, zebra-printers, epl

I'm using [LibUsbDotNet](http://libusbdotnet.sourceforge.net/V2/Index.html) to communicate with my GC420t Zebra printer.

It works great when it comes to printing:

```
MyUsbDevice = UsbDevice.OpenUsbDevice(MyUsbFinder);
if (MyUsbDevice == null) throw new Exception("Device Not Found.");

IUsbDevice wholeUsbDevice = MyUsbDevice as IUsbDevice;
if (!ReferenceEquals(wholeUsbDevice, null))
{
    wholeUsbDevice.SetConfiguration(1);
    wholeUsbDevice.ClaimInterface(0);
}

UsbEndpointWriter writer = MyUsbDevice.OpenEndpointWriter(WriteEndpointID.Ep01);

int bytesWritten;
if (writer.Write(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(someString), 2000, out bytesWritten) != ErrorCode.None)
    throw new Exception(UsbDevice.LastErrorString);
```

But I can't find a way to make my reader code work... Always returns 0 bytes read. I put it right at the end of the above code, **having my printer's lid opened** (which should surely give me some error code).

```
UsbEndpointReader reader = MyUsbDevice.OpenEndpointReader(ReadEndpointID.Ep01);

// above code...

ErrorCode ec = ErrorCode.None;
byte[] readBuffer = new byte[1024];
while (ec == ErrorCode.None)
{
    int bytesRead;
    ec = reader.Read(readBuffer, 5000, out bytesRead);
    Console.WriteLine("{0} bytes read", bytesRead);
    Console.Write(Encoding.Default.GetString(readBuffer, 0, bytesRead));
}
```

If you know how to make that work... Or if you know a better/faster/easier way to do that, I'll take it, thanks.

EDIT:
So I tried a few more things, did some more research.

[Accessing printer status using winspool](http://delradiesdev.blogspot.fr/2012/02/accessing-printer-status-using-winspool.html)
-> Returned 0 even though I removed the media from my printer, neat. Well, I guess it's just initialized to 0, and receives no value. This code is using the `OpenPrinter/GetPrinter/ClosePrinter` pattern.

[LibUsbDotNet](http://libusbdotnet.sourceforge.net/V2/Index.html)
-> Tried every listed way to read status, always 0 bytes read.

[RawPrinterHelper](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091/en-us)
-> Works for printing, didn't find a way to get my printer's status though.

Then I read something (can't remember on which site) saying **you had to read the status WHILE the printer was printing.** How can that be done?

EDIT:
For the sake of completeness, here's how I generate my commands for the printer (which will probably not help, since, once more, it works flawlessly when it comes to printing):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder().AppendLine()
    .AppendLine("N")
    .AppendLine("^ee") // The "give me an answer" code, also tested at the end of the commands, or as the only command (with newline and N)
    // more appending...
    .AppendLine(String.Format("P{0},{1}", 1, 1));
```

EDIT:
Just for the record, the reason why I'm quite sure you can get this GC420t's status... is because you just can, with Zebra Setup Utilities. If you send **^ee** with the provided tool (*Open Communication With Printer*), you get the error code properly. I just need to know how it does it.

Comment: what is ec? what is reader? **EDIT:** generally you can communicate through com port. Or you can send byte to printer by using winspool.Drv

Comment: Oops, copy/pasted too fast.

Comment: Its ok:) but generally you can do that with dllimport and winspool.Drv. It works perfect. I have used with zebra label printer 2844 successfully.

Comment: Any hint on where I should search for an example? Can't find one that does read and write on google D:

Comment: Well, most of the time the printer doesn't "say" anything in return to commands. To get the printer status, you need to send a special ZPL command first and *then* you get the answer. Do you send that command first?

Comment: If by first, you mean before trying to get the actual answer, yes, obviously :p .

Comment: If the solution was obvious, you wouldn't have to ask, would you :-)? My question was whether you send the **~HS** command.

Comment: It's EPL actually, the command is **^ee**, and it's sent, yes. I edited.

Comment: The EPL programming manual warns about this, ^ee is not supported on portable printers.  This one looks easy to carry around.  The printer manual also doesn't list the ZPL command as a supported command.  If you want to be sure then do contact the vendor.

Comment: @Hans THAT was interesting! Yet I don't understand why D:

Comment: Edited. This command works on the provided tools from Zebra.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the above class:

```
   public class cPrintHelper
{
    // Structure and API declarions:
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
    public class DOCINFOA
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pDocName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pOutputFile;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pDataType;
    }
    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint="OpenPrinterA", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling=true, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool OpenPrinter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string szPrinter, out IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pd);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint="ClosePrinter", SetLastError=true, ExactSpelling=true, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool ClosePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint="StartDocPrinterA", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling=true, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool StartDocPrinter( IntPtr hPrinter, Int32 level,  [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] DOCINFOA di);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint="EndDocPrinter", SetLastError=true, ExactSpelling=true, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool EndDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint="StartPagePrinter", SetLastError=true, ExactSpelling=true, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool StartPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint="EndPagePrinter", SetLastError=true, ExactSpelling=true, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool EndPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint="WritePrinter", SetLastError=true, ExactSpelling=true, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool WritePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount, out Int32 dwWritten );

    // SendBytesToPrinter()
    // When the function is given a printer name and an unmanaged array
    // of bytes, the function sends those bytes to the print queue.
    // Returns true on success, false on failure.
    public static bool SendBytesToPrinter( string szPrinterName, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount)
    {
        Int32    dwError = 0, dwWritten = 0;
        IntPtr    hPrinter = new IntPtr(0);
        DOCINFOA    di = new DOCINFOA();
        bool    bSuccess = false; // Assume failure unless you specifically succeed.

        di.pDocName = "My C#.NET RAW Document";
        di.pDataType = "RAW";

        // Open the printer.
        if( OpenPrinter( szPrinterName.Normalize(), out hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero ) )
        {
            // Start a document.
            if( StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di) )
            {
                // Start a page.
                if( StartPagePrinter(hPrinter) )
                {
                    // Write your bytes.
                    bSuccess = WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, out dwWritten);
                    EndPagePrinter(hPrinter);
                }
                EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
            }
            ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
        }
        // If you did not succeed, GetLastError may give more information
        // about why not.
        if( bSuccess == false )
        {
                dwError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        }
        return bSuccess;
    }

    public static bool SendFileToPrinter( string szPrinterName, string szFileName )
    {
        // Open the file.
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(szFileName, FileMode.Open);
        // Create a BinaryReader on the file.
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        // Dim an array of bytes big enough to hold the file's contents.
        Byte []bytes = new Byte[fs.Length];
        bool bSuccess = false;
        // Your unmanaged pointer.
        IntPtr pUnmanagedBytes = new IntPtr(0);
        int nLength;

        nLength = Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length);
        // Read the contents of the file into the array.
        bytes = br.ReadBytes( nLength );
        // Allocate some unmanaged memory for those bytes.
        pUnmanagedBytes = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(nLength);
        // Copy the managed byte array into the unmanaged array.
        Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
        // Send the unmanaged bytes to the printer.
        bSuccess = SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
        // Free the unmanaged memory that you allocated earlier.
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pUnmanagedBytes);
        return bSuccess;
    }
    public static bool SendStringToPrinter( string szPrinterName, string szString )
    {
        IntPtr pBytes;
        Int32 dwCount;
        // How many characters are in the string?
        dwCount = szString.Length;
        // Assume that the printer is expecting ANSI text, and then convert
        // the string to ANSI text.
        pBytes = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(szString);
        // Send the converted ANSI string to the printer.
        SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pBytes, dwCount);
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pBytes);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And the call:

```
cPrintHelper.SendStringToPrinter(printerName, fileIn);
```

fileIn is the escape sequence code.

fileIn should be something like this.  N
I8,D
Q120,24
q245
S4
D12
ZB
A100,10,0,3,2,2,N,"A"
A140,10,0,3,2,2,N,"B"
P1

1

This code works successful 5 years with zebra label printer 2844.

Hope that helps. :)

Comment: Before I try it, I'd like to know what does SendStringToPrinter here. Because if it's just going to, well, send a string to my printer, I'm already doing it with success. My issue is that I can't retrieve its status. + I already tested a code that looked a lot (and I mean, A LOT) like this one :p

Comment: @Kilazur this code is not a secret :) i have found it some where and i have used it! **EDIT** As i remembered at setup options i put printer generic text.

Comment: Yeah, it's [RawPrinterHelper](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091/en-us). But that doesn't tell me how to retrieve the status :p. How do you do it?

Comment: @Kilazur that was the class exactly :) As i remembered, i could not get the status. If find something post it please.

Comment: You didn't read the question meh D: I will post if I find... But I clearly hope someone does it before me, because else it will be in quite some time.

Comment: @Kilazur  Just for curiosity, why you why you need the status? Your aim is to print right?

Comment: The manual points out that the printer can only talk back across USB and serial port.  Besides that, the ReadPrinter() winapi function is of course missing :)

Comment: My aim is to pilot the printer remotely, so it would be pretty handy to be able to get it's errors.

Comment: @Kilazur the posted code is from web service that a handheld device connect and send the print.

Comment: Yeah, I know, and it works perfectly for printing. I just assume there's a "little something" I'm missing for it to work with my GC420t.

Comment: Be careful on the commands you send. If i remembered well you can send the commands for printing with out application. There is a way i think.

Comment: The commands are sent to the printer's spool, so yeah, they're "saved" even with the printer unplugged.

Answer (score 0):

Wrote a kiosk application using a KR403 last year. I was able to successfully print and poll the status of the printer to see if there was a paper jam low paper etc via usb using the blog post below.

http://danielezanoli.blogspot.com/2010/06/usb-communications-with-zebra-printers.html

```
var printerStatusCommand = Encoding.GetEncoding(850).GetBytes(@"~HQES");
try
{
    var zebraConnection = new ZebraUsbStream();

    zebraConnection.Write(printerStatusCommand, 0, printerStatusCommand.Length);

    var statusReturn = new byte[800];
    var bytesRead = zebraConnection.Read(statusReturn, 0, 800);

    if (bytesRead >= 132)
    {
        var stringResult = Encoding.Default.GetString(statusReturn.ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine(stringResult);
    }
}
catch
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error");
}
```

There was a lot of additional string/byte parsing of stringResult since the status values where stored as individual bits inside of of the return bytes but the printer docs covered the formatting pretty well.